# filter() with includes() to get partial matches

Tags: javascript

I have already tried the answer provided on this question [Using filter() in combination with includes() to get partial matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47458697/using-filter-in-combination-with-includes-to-get-partial-matches)

But it does not really solve the issue in my case since this answer only works if the text is smaller than the value in array.

I am using this code right now, which in the example I provided works and finds 'alex':

```js
let search = (list, text) =>
    list.filter(i => i.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()));

var items = ['john', 'bob', 'alex'];

var result = search(items, 'al');
console.log(result);
```

But, if I run `result = search(items, 'alexander')` it will not work, for my use-case I need to be able to find items this way as well.

To give context as to why I need this, I have users with an array of permission roles like `['admin.all', 'calendar.self', 'calendar.other']` and my menu items also have a parameter like `calendar` specifying which scopes they belong too (partially) and I use these 2 to determine if the user should see the menu item.

I want to be able to run `result = search(menuRoles, 'calendar.self')` and have the role `calendar` returned to me which then would mean I can show it.

Comment: Well, in your names example, no item `alexander` exists, so you wouldn't be able to find it unless you go through substrings.

Comment: You could split at `.` and check if the first part is included in the `menuRoles` array `i.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()split('.')[0])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if your search value also includes the current string

```js
let search = (list, text) =>
    list.filter(i => i.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()) || text.toLowerCase().includes(i.toLowerCase()));

var items = ['john', 'bob', 'alex'];

var result = search(items, 'alexander');
console.log(result);
```